# android asynctask giving networkonmainthread exception

Tags: android, networking, gps, android-asynctask, location

```
case R.id.bus_item:

            new GetProductDetails().execute();

            CharSequence coordinates[] = {tvlat.getText(),tvlong.getText()};
            double lat = Double.parseDouble((String) coordinates[0]);
            double lng = Double.parseDouble((String) coordinates[1]);

            GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6),(int)(lng * 1E6));

            mc.animateTo(p);
            mc.setZoom(18);
            mapView.invalidate();
```

netwok code

```
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapSimple.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading location details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_LOCATION); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            //txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            tvlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_lat1);
                            tvlong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_long1);

                            // display product data in EditText

                            tvlat.setText(product.getString(TAG_LAT));
                            tvlong.setText(product.getString(TAG_LONG));

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Logcat

```
12-04 09:41:22.038: W/dalvikvm(841): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.aunsync_alpha.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.aunsync_alpha.MapSimple$GetProductDetails$1.run(MapSimple.java:135)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-04 09:41:22.088: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the code is returning the networkonmainthread error. But there is an async in the code.
Please help.

Comment: plz, post your task code and log cat..

Comment: I don't see network code or asynctask in your code. Plz add error log + relevant code

Comment: You are making a network call on the UI thread. There is no need for that `runOnUiThread()`. Instead do the work directly in `doInBackground()` and only do the updates in `onPostExecute()`. Also, please take some time to read up about `AsyncTask` and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use runOnUiThread. Your doInBackground method should looks like this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {    

                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_LOCATION); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);  




                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      tvlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_lat1);
        tvlong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_long1);

        // display product data in EditText

        tvlat.setText(product.getString(TAG_LAT));
        tvlong.setText(product.getString(TAG_LONG));
```

here you are tying to access Ui elements TextView in doInBackground. so move this line in `onPostExecute` method  of `AsyncTask` :

remove runOnUiThread from doInBackground move all Ui elemets to  onPostExecute .change your code as:

```
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, Arraylist<String>> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapSimple.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading location details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected Arraylist<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
Arraylist<String> arraylist=new Arraylist<String>();

                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_LOCATION); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found


                            // display product data in EditText

                arraylist.add(TAG_LAT);
                arraylist.add(TAG_LONG);

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            return arraylist;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(Arraylist<String> arraylist) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
                     // Edit Text
                            //txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            tvlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_lat1);
                            tvlong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_long1);
                            tvlat.setText(product.getString(arraylist.get(0)));
                            tvlong.setText(product.getString(arraylist.get(1)));
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: see my edit answer just use this GetProductDetails class  instead of your . then your code work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the method `runOnUiThread` **inside** `doInBackground`... the part that modifies the ui should be moved to `onPostExecute`..

it should be..

```
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

int success;
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapSimple.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading location details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread


                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_LOCATION); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);



                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();

         if (success == 1) {// product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        //txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        tvlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_lat1);
                        tvlong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_long1);

                        // display product data in EditText

                        tvlat.setText(product.getString(TAG_LAT));
                        tvlong.setText(product.getString(TAG_LONG));
                        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the method `runOnUiThread` inside `doInBackground` and `UI` modifications should be moved to `onPostExecute`.

Thanks...